# how to fetch HTTP post request from webhook API in ruby on rails 3.2

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, http-post

I am new to ROR. I am developing `SMS` service for my rails application. The app has to receive an asynchronous `HTTP POST request` from `webhook API` and has to generate an auto reply.
I am working with `rails 3.2.13`.

Can anyone tell me how to fetch this `JSON` request in rails?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this video from [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/348-the-rails-api-gem) i am sure that it will help you out with what you are looking for. feel free to ask more questions after watch the video

Comment: Thanks for answer. I am trying to implement this https://telerivet.com/help/api/webhook/receiving PHP script in ROR. can you guide me how to implement this?